# The tutorial's problem about addHero (where the new id comes from)

Tags: angular, typescript

When I want to add a new hero, I will use

add(string) function from heroes/heroes.component.ts

```
  add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.heroes.push(hero);
      });
  }
```

and

addHero(Hero) function from heroes.service.ts

```
  addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newHero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${newHero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
    );
  }
```

I want to know where the new ID is coming from.

This is the live example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ombxjmbjedp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses in [in-memory-web-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) module to emulate CRUD operations over a RESTy API.

This module adds custom HttpInterceptor to interceptors chain. Under the hood that interceptor is also responsible for generating id for entity.

```
// Create entity
// Can update an existing entity too if post409 is false.
protected post({ collection, collectionName, headers, id, req, resourceUrl, url }: RequestInfo)
   : ResponseOptions {
  const item = this.clone(this.getJsonBody(req));

  // tslint:disable-next-line:triple-equals
  if (item.id == undefined) {
    try {
      item.id = id || this.genId(collection, collectionName);
```

You can also write your own function for generating id in your InMemoryDataService. That's exactly that we [can see](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ombxjmbjedp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fin-memory-data.service.ts) in that example:

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
 ...

// Overrides the genId method to ensure that a hero always has an id.
// If the heroes array is empty,
// the method below returns the initial number (11).
// if the heroes array is not empty, the method below returns the highest
// hero id + 1.
genId(heroes: Hero[]): number {
  return heroes.length > 0 ? Math.max(...heroes.map(hero => hero.id)) + 1 : 11;
}
```

Comment: so ID are generating from in-memory-web-api .

No wonder even I deleted genID can  not stop ID

Answer (score -1):

```
    addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
        return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
          tap((newHero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${newHero.id}`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
        );
      }
```

In this you can see, While calling this service function we are sending data object from heroes.component.ts ,
 hero: Hero  at this point we are using Hero as defined variable

```
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
 // which is further allocated another instance 
 tap((newHero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${newHero.id}`));
```

All the data is in newHero, From it we can acess the id.
Thanks